# Login Problem looped

Tags: login

when i login, the screen gets black for 1 sec (with 1 white bar in top left corner) and i get relocated to login.

This happens since i tried to install the "suckless dwm" window manager. Without sudo, i did "make clean install" and rebooted.

I had to reset my password to enter with tty. But I'm stuck now. Maybe this gives u an indication:

- The .Xauthority & .xinitrc files doesnt exist.
- I reinstalled the xserver
- I tried another display manager - lightDM
- after login via tty it says "Cannot open display 'default display'"
- "xrandr --listmonitors" says "Can't open display"

System:

- Ubuntu 18.04.04 LTS
- Internal Graphics - Intel
- 5 years old

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 0):

A good option is to check the system's logs
Type `cd /var/log/syslogs` to see if you can find the issue